# Visual Studio - filter nvcc warnings away

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cuda, nvidia

I'm writing a CUDA program but I'm getting the obnoxious warning:

```
Warning: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space
```

this is coming from nvcc and I can't disable it.

Is there any way to filter out warning from third-party tools (like nvcc)?

I'm asking for a way to filter out of the output window log errors/warnings coming from custom build tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same annoying warnings, I found help on this thread: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212875/resolving-thrust-cuda-warnings-cannot-tell-what-pointer-points-to).

You can either remove the -G flag on the nvcc command line,

or

change the compute_10,sm_10 to compute_20,sm_20 in the Cuda C/C++ options of your project if you're using Visual Studio.